# Cq engine persistent map giving exception "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: database is locked"

Tags: database, sqlite, persistent, cqengine

I am trying  to store my Java Cq engine map on disk.  The map is huge  and  multiple threads  are accessing it  concurrently.

I am getting:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: database is locked

I am  doing this  to  remove   clear my heap  space. Slow search is not problem.

```
DiskPersistence<PimcoImsModel, String> persistence = DiskPersistence.onPrimaryKeyInFile(PimcoImsModel.ID, new File(getSourceDb()));

memory = new ConcurrentIndexedCollection<PimcoImsModel> (persistence);
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am facing the same issue.